# Error: Multiple components match node with tagname app-contact

Tags: angular, service, angular-material

I have an Angular Material application where I have a list of cards, each representing a `Contact`. that is, an object with various attributes, such as first name, last name, email, image, etc.

To display this list, I simply iterate over the list of `Contact`s:

```
<mat-list role="list" class="contacts-container-box">
  <div class="application-box" role="listitem" *ngFor="let contact of contacts">
    <app-contact [contact]="contact"></app-contact>
  </div>
</mat-list>
```

The `app-contact` component is then responsible to show the details of each `Contact`. However, if I try to run the application as it is, I get no errors at compile time, but in the browser console I get the following:
[image: error]

I tried to reproduce the issue on StackBlitz, and I get this:

[image: error2]

Anyway, it doesn't work as expected. Notice that this error only occurs if I uncomment the method `getContactImage()` in the `ContactsService`, if I comment it everything works except, of course, for the image which is not loaded.

Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tnb6rv

Comment: I moved `getImageFromService` to `ngOnInit()` and it seems to be working? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m2hqrs?file=src/app/contact/contact.component.ts. For your original error, you probably have 2 components with the same `app-contact` tagname (maybe a bad copy/paste). Or maybe your component is declared in 2 modules? Just do a search for `app-contact` in your project

Comment: The error just went away as soon as I moved the call to the method inside `ngOnInit()`. By the way, I made sure there was not a duplicate tag name, so it seems like some kind of weird approach of Angular.

Comment: All Input parameters are allowed in ngOnInit | ngOnChanges method, which is why you got an error in the constructor. When an error occurs in a component, its destroy is not called, and then we get an error with the same component name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happened to me because I had a console.log() in constructor of a variable from @Input.

Probably this problem is already solved, but here's information for other people

Answer (score 0):

`@Input` values are undefined in the constructor. In `contact.component.ts` you are trying to access `this.contact` in `getImageFromService()` which is called from the constructor.

Fix: move the call to `getImageFromService()` to `ngOnInit(){}`